# Working on a Tourist Visa

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, work

I own a full service agency within the US and my girlfriend is one of my employees (full time contractor from overseas). She is planning on coming to the US to visit me and my family, I was wondering if there are any rules I should be aware about as she plans to get her B2 visa -- few questions like:

1.) Is she legally allowed to work for me while she is in the US, since she is a full time contractor getting paid in her international country?

2.) If she is coming here, is she expected to take off from work for this time and need a letter from her employer stating she will not be working?

Comment: In case it's not clear from the linked duplicate, she absolutely cannot work while she is in the US on a B-2 visa, nor can she do so with a B-1 visa.  It doesn't matter where the money is going; what matters is where it's coming from (but that is far from the only factor).  As to the strategy for her visa application, which you're asking about in point 2, you might edit this question to focus on that, whereupon it might be reopened, or you can ask a new question.

Comment: I'll be stronger about that - she is not allowed to work for you, even if you don't pay her.